# How to replace a number by its corresponding string (low/high) in bash?

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, replace

I have a file:

```
property(Address1, 4.5)
property(Address2, 2.2)
property(Address3, 9.0)
property(Address4, 3.4)
---
```

I want to replace the floating points based on some conditions (For example: if the number is between 2 and 4, I will replace it by Low, otherwise High) to produce this:

```
property(Address1, High)
property(Address2, Low)
property(Address3, High)
property(Address4, Low)
---
```

My try: (1) First extract the number using $. (2) Check whether the condition satisfies (3) then print it. But in this process I am failing to output the Address* to the output file.

Comment: The process you describe sounds correct. After you calculate whether the floating point is high or low, you can use something like `sed` to replace the number in the string with high or low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does (strictly) what you ask for:

```
awk '{ print $1, (($2>2)&&($2<4))?"Low)":"High)" }'
```

But it is taking advantage of the fact that an string like `9.0)` (with the trailing parenthesis) is converted to the number `9` by awk. That may fail if an space gets added for example.

A more strict solution is to also use the closing parenthesis as a field delimiter to remove it from the contents of field number `2`.

```
awk -F'[ )]' '{print $1,(($2>2)&&($2<4))?"Low)":"High)"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with if and else condition

```
sed "s/)$//g" filename| awk '{if($2 > 2 && $2 < 4) {$2="low)";print $0}else{$2="high)";print $0}}'
    property(Address1, high)
    property(Address2, low)
    property(Address3, high)
    property(Address4, low)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, assuming numbers are in the format `[-]<digits>[.<digits>]`, and matching on them wherever they are in the input provided they're neither preceded nor followed by *word* characters (so `Address1` is not changed to `AddressHigh` for instance):

```
<input perl -pe 's{(?<!\w)-?\d[\d.]*(?!\w)}{$& >=2 && $& <=4 ? "Low" : "High"}ge'
```